# How to change folder permission using FileZilla Client on Windows for Filezilla Server on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, ftp, wordpress, chmod

I have tried many things including using Cygwin with a domain user because Windows Server cannot use CHMOD which FileZilla tries, but nothing worked sadly.

I am open to using a different FTP Client if nessesary.

This is all to change the permissions for some folders for the FTP user from "Not Writable" to "Writable" for Wordpress

Comment: Windows has a completely different permission scheme to Unix, which FTP was designed for. You'll have to log in to the server directly to make these changes. Or consider switching to Linux, which would just make running the web site a lot easier overall.

Comment: That is sadly not possible. We are bound to the windows server and I need those permissions on the user that will work with FTP for wordpress. There has to be another way because otherwise wordpress would be unusable on windows server which is possible.

Comment: Why can't you log in and change the permissions in the normal way?

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla FTP server does not support changing file permissions.

Nor I'm aware of any other Windows FTP server that can do that.

So I'm afraid that if FTP if the only access you have to the server, you are out of luck.